# Show $U^TQQ^TU$ = $Q^TUU^TQ$ $= I$, if $X=UDV^T$ is the skinny SVD of X and $X=QR$ is its skinny QRD.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have that $X$ is a full rank n by p matrix with $n>p$. Let $X=UDV^T$ denote the skinny SVD of X and let $X = QR$ denote its skinny QRD. (Skinny is also sometimes referred to as economic).

I need to show $U^TQQ^TU$ = $Q^TUU^TQ$ = I.

To do this, do I need to equate $QR = UDV^T$? If so, whats the relationship between these two decompositions where I could proceed to show the required?

Thank you

Comment: Look at $X^{T}X$ and its inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Because your decomposition is thin, you have that $D$ is invertible. Then
$$
(U^TQQ^TU)DV^T=U^TQQ^T\,(UDV^T)=U^TQQ^T\,QR=U^TQR=U^TUDV^T=DV^T.
$$
As $DV^T$ is invertible, we get
$$
U^TQQ^TU=I.
$$
Similarly,
$$
Q^TUU^TQ\,R=Q^TUU^TUDV^T=Q^TUDV^T=Q^TQR=R,
$$
and from $R$ invertible we get
$$
Q^TUU^TQ=I.
$$

Note that $U^TU=I$ and $Q^TQ=I$ follow from the fact that both matrices have pairwise orthogonal columns.